# VBA: Compile error, Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment - .find

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to find the row number of a cell which contains the value “SOI 1”. The message box returns the correct number, but when I try to assign that number to a variable for later use I get the compile error:

“Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment”

I’m fairly new to VBA, so any help you guys can provide would be amazing!

```
Public Sub Testing()

Dim rFind As Range
Dim row_SOI1 As Integer

test = "SOI 1"

With Range("A1:A100")
Set rFind = .Find(What:="SOI 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox rFind.Row
    If test = "SOI 1" Then:
        rFind.Row = row_SOI1
    End If
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you want this `row_SOI1 = rFind.Row`

Comment: You are right! Thank you! Good ol’ VBA syntax...

Comment: Note: Don't use `Integer` for row counting. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Always use `Long` instead of `Integer` there is [no benefit in using `Integer` in VBA at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613).